# I get a permission denied when trying to install appdirs? - Python

Tags: python, permissions

My error:

```
C:\Users\monke\hangoutsbot>pip install appdirs requests
Collecting appdirs
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Installing collected packages: appdirs
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\appdirs.py'
```

I keep getting this problem I'm using Python 3.6 and pip 9.0.1 for 3.6...

Comment: Open an elevated terminal (as admin) and rerun.

Comment: Well that was simple.... ;-;

Comment: I tried marking this as a dupe, but it turns out this solution is not mentioned there. So, I'll post an answer.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\monke\hangoutsbot\hangupsbot\hangupsbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\monke\hangoutsbot\hangupsbot\hangupsbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import appdirs, argparse, asyncio, gettext, logging, logging.config, os, shutil, signal, sys, time
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appdirs'  ;        I'm still getting this problem

Comment: What is that error?

Comment: I don't know I'm knew to Python.... I was trying to install a googlehangouts bot and run it and then it said appdirs could not be found so I installed it and it stills says it cannot be found...

Comment: Now that you've installed it, come out of elevated prompt and run as normal.

Comment: I tried in both admin and normal and am still getting the same message instead of a successful installation. Edit: Nevermind, but I'm still getting this error C:\Users\monke>python C:\Users\monke\hangoutsbot\hangupsbot\hangupsbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\monke\hangoutsbot\hangupsbot\hangupsbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import hangups
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hangups' even though I already cloned the repository...